# Windows 7 not recognizing the 'j' key on my keyboard

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard

Every key on my Razoe Black Window Ultimate keyboard is recognized by Windows 7, except the 'j' key.  Nothing happens when I hit it.  I've moved the keyboard to my Macbook and it works fine there.  The keyboard driver is up to date.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Does it work on other keyboards?

Comment: J is a numeric keypad key.  Try toggling NumLk a few times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's really no reason one letter should stop working unless you have mapped it to something else on the Windows machine. I recommend removing all of the software and drivers for the keyboard and re-installing it. If that doesn't work, I would contact Razor technical support and see if this is a common issue. But I suspect it's just mapped to something else, being a gaming keyboard and all. Check your startup processes and see if there's anything weird in there as well. (type msconfig into Run)

Comment: Turns out there was a macro set against the J key that did nothing.  I have no idea how it got there, but when the J key was pressed the empty macro ran.  I removed the macro and it works correctly now.

Answer (score 0):

Steps for fixing this issue:

1. Open Razer Synapse.
2. Select keyboard.
3. Click on the key which is not working.
4. Select any other function than the default.
5. Click *Save*.
6. Then click on the key once again and select default again.
7. Click *Save*.